# How to solve a system with non static coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How does one solve the following system for $ w, x, y, z $ given $ a, b, c, d $?

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1               & \frac{w}{w+y+z} & \frac{w}{w+x+z} & \frac{w}{w+x+y} \\
 \frac{x}{x+y+z} & 1               & \frac{x}{w+x+z} & \frac{x}{w+x+y} \\
 \frac{y}{x+y+z} & \frac{y}{w+y+z} & 1               & \frac{y}{w+x+y} \\
 \frac{z}{x+y+z} & \frac{z}{w+y+z} & \frac{z}{w+x+z} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
 w \\
 x \\
 y \\
 z
\end{bmatrix}
=
2
\begin{bmatrix}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
 d
\end{bmatrix}$$

$a,b,c,d,w,x,y,z$ are all $\gt 0$ and $\le .5$ 
$$w+x+y+z=1 \qquad a+b+c+d=1$$

Example: given $ a, b, c, d $ what is $ w, x, y, z $?

$$a=\frac{2}{5} \qquad b=\frac{1}{5} \qquad c=\frac{1}{5} \qquad d=\frac{1}{5} $$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1             & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & 1             & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5} & 1             & \frac{1}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{6}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{4}{5} \\
 \frac{2}{5} \\
 \frac{2}{5} \\
 \frac{2}{5}
\end{bmatrix}
=
2
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{2}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{5}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ w=\frac{1}{2} \qquad x=\frac{1}{6} \qquad y=\frac{1}{6} \qquad z=\frac{1}{6} $$

How did I find this solution? Searching. I started by setting $ w=\frac{2}{5}, x=\frac{1}{5}, y=\frac{1}{5}, z=\frac{1}{5}$. I increased $w$ while decreasing $x$, $y$ and $z$ till converging on the desired values.

1 more example for good measure, the following is approximate:
$$ a=2/5 \qquad b=2/5 \qquad c=1/10 \qquad d=1/10 $$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1        & .7280268 & .4572917 & .4572917 \\
 .7280268 & 1        & .4572917 & .4572917 \\
 .1359866 & .1359866 & 1        & .0854166 \\
 .1359866 & .1359866 & .0854166 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
 0.421304541 \\
 0.421304541 \\
 0.07869459 \\
 0.07869459
\end{bmatrix}
\approx
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{4}{5} \\
 \frac{4}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{5}
\end{bmatrix}
\approx
2
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{2}{5} \\
 \frac{2}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{10} \\
 \frac{1}{10}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ w \approx 0.421304541 \qquad x \approx 0.421304541 \qquad y \approx 0.07869459 \qquad z \approx 0.07869459 $$

Edit:
Another route includes root-finding algorithms like [Brent's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Brent.27s_method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look for solutions by writing the system in this way

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1               & \frac{w}{w+y+z} & \frac{w}{w+x+z} & \frac{w}{w+x+y} \\
 \frac{x}{x+y+z} & 1               & \frac{x}{w+x+z} & \frac{x}{w+x+y} \\
 \frac{y}{x+y+z} & \frac{y}{w+y+z} & 1               & \frac{y}{w+x+y} \\
 \frac{z}{x+y+z} & \frac{z}{w+y+z} & \frac{z}{w+x+z} & 1 \\
\frac{a}{w}&\frac{b}{x}&\frac{c}{y}&\frac{d}{z}&\\
1&1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
 w \\
 x \\
 y \\
 z
\end{bmatrix}
=
2
\begin{bmatrix}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
 d \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$

and I would use a software that apply the Gauss-Jordan algorithm to the matrix.
Now I have a simpler system in 6 equations and 8 variables. To the solutions (dependent by two variables) I will apply the inequalities

$a,b,c,d,w,x,y,z \ $
are all$ \
>0 \ 
and 
≤.5
$